# how can i get the list item data i click on?

Tags: android, list, get

i have some listview and SimpleAdapter

```
List<HashMap<String, Object>> dataList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put(ITEMTITLE, getString(R.string.broadcast_street_1_text));
    map.put(ITEMDESCR, getString(R.string.broadcast_request_1_text));
    dataList.add(map);

    map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put(ITEMTITLE, getString(R.string.broascast_street_2_text)); 
    map.put(ITEMDESCR, getString(R.string.broadcast_request_2_text));
    dataList.add(map);

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, 
                                               dataList,
                                               R.layout.broadcast_list_item,
                                               new String[] {ITEMTITLE, ITEMDESCR}, 
                                               new int[] {R.id.broadcast_list_item_title, R.id.broadcast_list_item_descr}); 

    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

so, when i click on the some list item i need to change activity.

```
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long arg3) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getParent(), BroadcastDataActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("street", arg0.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
            intent.putExtra("time", arg0.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
            parentActivity = (WorldTaxiActivityGroup) getParent();
            parentActivity.startChildActivity("BroadcastData", intent);
        }
    });
```

But  arg0.getItemAtPosition(position)  returns just an Object of data
Help me, please, how can i get the data correcly?

Comment: I'm confused, What is the difference b/w `Object of data` and `correct data`

Comment: mmm...it is an Object (type)..how can i get data from it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long arg3) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getParent(), BroadcastDataActivity.class);
            HashMap<String, Object> item = dataList.get(position);
            intent.putExtra("street", item.get(ITEMTITLE).toString();
            intent.putExtra("time", item.get(ITEMDESCR).toString().toString());
            parentActivity = (WorldTaxiActivityGroup) getParent();
            parentActivity.startChildActivity("BroadcastData", intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Though my problem was little different but It gave me clue to get it solved

Answer (score 2):

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long arg3) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getParent(), BroadcastDataActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("street", dataList.get(position).get("ITEMTITLE"));
            intent.putExtra("time", dataList.get(position).get("ITEMDESCR"));
            parentActivity = (WorldTaxiActivityGroup) getParent();
            parentActivity.startChildActivity("BroadcastData", intent);
        }
    });
```